# Would running Chrome on Wine trick a website into thinking that's Windows?

Tags: chrome, wine, spoofing

The website I want to use blocks part of the content for Linux users for some reason. I know about the user agent and how to change it. It works for websites like whatismybrowser, but it doesn't for this one. Not even changing the browser. Say I'm on Firefox and change it to be Chrome for Windows, it still detects as being Firefox on Linux, so there is extra technical wizardry going on there that's beyond my knowledge on the subject.

But then I remember Wine is a thing. I've never really used it (only Proton on Steam), but the way I understand how it works, it basically reverse engineered Windows libraries for running Windows apps, so depending on the wizardry that's going on in that website, maybe I could trick it into believing it's running on Windows.

But I don't want to mess too much with this sort of stuff if I don't have too, hence the question here.

Alternatively, I would also accept as an answer other methods to spoof the OS for this website.

Comment: Javascript makes available the [`navigator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator) object which has things like `platform` and `appName`.  This is likely how they are identifying your browser.  I cannot find a plugin that does what you are asking, but see if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38808968/change-navigator-platform-on-chrome-firefox-or-ie-to-test-os-detection-code) answer helps generate a solution.